# Big Query: Project not found

Tags: google-bigquery

Project xw-direct-analog-k has been created. I can see it in the Manage Projects page.
I am part of the team, I have the 'Can Edit' permission. I can see it in the Team page.
Billing has been enabled for this project too.

But if I switch to this project in the BigQuery web interface I get the Project not found error message.

What have I missed?

Best,

François

Answer (score 0):

Is this project part of a google apps domain? If so, there is a known issue that affects project lookup. The only current workaround is to create a domain with a non-domain user (e.g. an @gmail account).

Comment: Note that this bug should be fixed now. Please let us know if you continue to see the issue.